# CSS: Centering image within container

Tags: html, css

First of all, I'm kinda new to CSS, so forgive me if this is a stupid question, or my code doesn't make much sense - I've tried solving my issue, and haven't had much luck so far.

I'm having trouble centering an image, inside a div which should make a border around the image - I've made a JFiddle to further explain:

https://jsfiddle.net/9yxco7ez/

The idea is that the image should be in the center of the bordered div around it.

HTML:

```
 <div class="sponsorLogos">
  <ul class="sponsorGallery">
   <li class="sponsorImg" ng-repeat="path in sponsorLogos">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://www.garcard.com/images/garcard_symbol.png">
    </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sponsorLogos ul li {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  border: solid 5px #e0e5eb;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sponsorsDiv .sponsorLogos img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I've found a few topics on here to try and solve my problem, but haven't yet succeeded.. I know theres probably the right answer out there, but I haven't been able to find it, so sorry in advance if this question is answered elsewhere..

Comment: Will the blocks containing the logos always have a fixed width and height?

Comment: I can't see a: `.sponsorsDiv` div in your HTML. Could you just remove that from your CSS selector...